# How to solve this logical error while updating data of multiple jtables?

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel

#### Background:

I am trying to update multiple `jtables` simultaneously as in the image below. Each `jtable` has a model and it is attached to a `TableModelListener`.

Whenever I set a value in a cell of a particular `jtable` I need to remove the `TableModelListener`, set the value, and re-add the `TableModelListener` again, otherwise I get an error if I don’t follow this sequence. This sequence seems to work successfully on ONE `jtable`,

However, when I update data in multiple `jtables` based on this sequence, I will face logical error.

#### Logical error:

when I add for example 3 rows in the first `jtable` based on the uploaded image, the first row will be added in the first `jtable`, however the second two rows will be added in the last `jtable.

#### Question:

How can I update all rows in multiple `jtables` and those tables have models and attached to `TableModelListeners?` please do not tell me to use `fireTableDataChanged();` method because it will only trigger the `TableModelListener` and fire the `updateJTables` method.

[image]

**Comment:**

> when I comment (erase) method `updateJTables` and run the below Example,
>   adding rows in the activated tab will be correct in other words, *the
>   problem will disappear*. therefore, the problem i assume is happening
>   when i am removing and re adding the `TableModelListener` in method
>   `updateJTables`. what is the type of the problem? I really want to
>   understand what is happening.

#### Sample Code (short example, modified):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JT {

    private static javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabPane;
    private javax.swing.JButton addRow;
    private javax.swing.JButton addTable;
    private javax.swing.JPanel topPanel;
    private static DefaultTableModel modelItemTable;
    private static javax.swing.JTable itemTable;
    private static TableModelListener itemTableListener;

    public JT(){
        BorderLayout bl=new BorderLayout();
        JFrame f=new JFrame("example of the problem");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        f.setLayout(bl);
        topPanel=new javax.swing.JPanel();
        tabPane=new javax.swing.JTabbedPane(); 
        addRow=new javax.swing.JButton("Add Row");
        addTable=new javax.swing.JButton("Add Table");
        topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        topPanel.add(addRow);
        topPanel.add(addTable);
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(modelItemTable!=null){
                    defineItemModel();
                    for(int i=1; i<4; i++){
                        modelItemTable.addRow(new Object[]{
                                "Hello World"+i,                  //name
                                (Math.random()*10)              //Cost
                               }
                            );
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        addTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addTab();
            }
        });
        itemTableListener= new TableModelListener(){
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                 if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE || e.getType() == TableModelEvent.INSERT) {
                    updateJTables(); 
                }
            }
        };
        f.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.add(tabPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }//end of constructor

    public static javax.swing.JTable buildItemTable(){
        itemTable= new javax.swing.JTable();
        modelItemTable=new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {},
            new String [] {
                "name", 
                "Cost"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Object.class,     //name
                java.lang.Double.class     //Cost

            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                true,       //name
                false       //Cost
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        };
        modelItemTable.addTableModelListener(itemTableListener);
        itemTable.setModel(modelItemTable);
        return itemTable;
    }//end of buildItemTable

    public static List<javax.swing.JTable> defineMultipleItemJTables(){
        Component[] components= tabPane.getComponents();
        List<javax.swing.JTable> jTableList=new ArrayList<javax.swing.JTable>();
        JScrollPane scrollPane;
        JViewport viewport;
        for(int i=0; i<components.length; i++){
            if(components[i] instanceof JScrollPane){
                scrollPane=(JScrollPane) components[i];
                viewport = scrollPane.getViewport(); 
                jTableList.add((javax.swing.JTable)viewport.getView());
            }
        }
        return jTableList;
    }//end of defineMultipleItemModel

    public static void defineItemModel(){
        JScrollPane scrollPane=(JScrollPane) tabPane.getSelectedComponent();
        if(scrollPane!=null){
            JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport(); 
            javax.swing.JTable selectedJTable = (javax.swing.JTable)viewport.getView();
            modelItemTable=(DefaultTableModel)selectedJTable.getModel() ;
            itemTable=selectedJTable;
        }
    }//end of defineItemModel

    public void updateJTables(){
        List<javax.swing.JTable> jTables=defineMultipleItemJTables();
        if(jTables.size()>0){
            for(int i=0; i<jTables.size(); i++){
                modelItemTable=(DefaultTableModel) jTables.get(i).getModel();
                itemTable=jTables.get(i);
                if(itemTable.getRowCount()>0){
                    modelItemTable.removeTableModelListener(itemTableListener);
                    for(int c=0; c<jTables.get(i).getRowCount(); c++){
//                        calculate(c);
                    }
                    modelItemTable.addTableModelListener(itemTableListener);
                }  
            }
        }
    }//end of updateJTables

     public static void addTab(){
        tabPane.addTab("New_Tab",new javax.swing.JScrollPane(buildItemTable()));
        ChangeListener tabPaneListener=new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                modelItemTable.fireTableDataChanged();
            }       
        };
        tabPane.addChangeListener(tabPaneListener);      
    }//end of addTab

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JT j=new JT();
    }//end of main

}//end of class JT
```

*please let me know if the above code is still big. although after this modification, it is kind of difficult to make the above example shorter, because i will not be able to show or define the problem. If you have any comments or questions please ask. Thanks*

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I will create short example and upload the code, thanks for your help

Comment: Do the tables use the same model or are the models different? The basic process would be something like, detect the event (from TableModelListener), set a flag, which when true would mean you would ignore any further updates, update all other tables, reset the ignore flag. You might even be able to use the original TableModelEvent and simply modify the source (if this is important) or just update the models directly, cause your no longer responding to possible events ;)

Comment: Given the fact that the tables are in different tabs, I would argue that you only need update a table when it's tab is actually activated, otherwise it seem like a complete waste of time

Comment: you are correct regarding the tabs activated at one time, however, i have on the main program a SIDE PANEL that has some values to change that will affect all tabs, therefore i need to update all JTABLES within the TAB PANE, there are updates in each JTABLE AND there are also updates on ALL JTABLES.

Comment: i have uploaded a complete example of the problem, please help! when you run it, there will be two jTables and two buttons. first button to add a table and second is to add rows based on selecting items from the first jtable.

Comment: to answer your question MadProgrammer, those Tables do NOT use the same models. thanks.

Comment: Those uncompilable code sections posted are neither minimal nor complete!  Please **read** the document I linked to.

Comment: i am working on it, thanks again.

Comment: i have created the same example in Eclipse editor, tested it and it is working. please let me know if you have any question or comment. it is compilable. all you have to do is copy the code and run it. thanks again for your time.

Comment: Questions about debugging on Stack Overflow require a [mcve]. The code that you have posted is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to ensure that the code **in your question** is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more). As it is your question is off topic for Stack Overflow.